# How to vertically center content in CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to vertically-align two divs on one side with a larger div on the other.

Here is a mockup of what I was looking to achieve:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/8o2CCwA]

The two smaller divs on the left are taking up considerably more space - it looks like each one is taking up 50% of the height. I understand I need to first tighten the divs so it is only the height of the amount of content in the actual div, and then somehow horizontally align to the larger green div.

I've tried using `align-items`, `justify-content`, and `grid-template-rows`, but I'm not getting the responsive output that I'm looking for.

```css
h2,
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}

.object {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'item1'
    'item2'
    'item3';
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item2 item1' 
    'item3 item1';
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-container>div {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="object">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p style="margin: 0px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the grid items into flex containers.

Use `auto` margins to push them into place.

```css
.grid-container > div {
  display: flex;             /* new */
  flex-direction: column;    /* new */
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item2 {
  margin-top: auto;          /* new */
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item3 {
  margin-bottom: auto;       /* new */
  grid-area: item3;
}

h2,
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.object {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;

}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'item1'
    'item2'
    'item3';
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'item2 item1'
    'item3 item1';
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="object">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p style="margin: 0px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h2,
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
  align-self: self-end;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
  align-self: self-start;
}

.object {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'item1'
    'item2'
    'item3';
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    'item2 item1' 
    'item3 item1';
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-container>div {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="object">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p style="margin: 0px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `align-self: self-end/end` on the div [`.item2`] that you want to pull down and use `align-self: self-start/start` on the div [`.item3`] that you want to keep at the top. For reference you can go through this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout